# Docusign / SFDC Web service callout failed: Unable to parse callout response. Apex type not found for element isTLSv12Required

Tags: salesforce, integration, docusignapi, apex

I runned into an issue when trying to connect docusign to SFDC, here are the steps followed :

1. Went on my docusign admin portal in Salesforce
2. Into Account, clicked modify account configuration
3. Logged in with my docusign account and then salesforce user account (both admin on respective platforms)
4. I've added Docusign IP addresses in network access in Salesforce
5. Tried to connect and received the following error message : Web service callout failed: Unable to parse callout response. Apex type not found for element isTLSv12Required

Does anyone know how to solve this ? Thanks

Comment: You might need to add more elements; for example, what does the callout response return?

Comment: Thanks @AlBlue, im quite new to this, how can I find this information to share it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this might be an error related to an older version of the DocuSign eSignature for Salesforce managed package. Do you have version 7.8.1 installed? If not, try updating and try again.

If you're on a version that's 7.x.x or above, you should be able to update straight to 7.8.1 without issues. If you're on 6.9.x or below, there are some changes in Custom Button format you'll need to be aware of (Documented Here: https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/DFS-URL-buttons-for-Lightning-basic-setup-limitations). In either case, I'd recommend updating in a Sandbox first to confirm everything is compatible.

As a temporary workaround, you should be able to configure Connect from the DocuSign side. Log in to the DocuSign web console and navigate to Settings > Connect > Salesforce > Reconfigure Login to attempt to connect DS to SF from the DS side. This may allow you to bypass the error.

Comment: It was an issue with the version indeed, it was 7.4 so I was able to upgrade it directly. Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Good to hear! Since this resolved the issue, can you accept the answer?